# Отказ в доступе к переносу папок

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

Я пытаюсь переместить файлы из одной директории в другую, но у меня ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:/scripts123/Август_Фавн_dz_7/project_2/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.replace(path+"\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp", path+'\my_project\\templates')
 PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp'
-> 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\templates'
```

Вот мой код, помогите пожалуйста:

```
import os
import shutil
path = os.getcwd()
list_of_temp = []
with open('walk.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for item in os.walk(path):
        f.writelines(str(item) + '\n')

with open('walk.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.find('templates') != -1:
            list_of_temp.append(line)

os.replace(path+"\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp", path+'\my_project\\templates')
os.replace(path+"\my_project\mainapp\\templates\mainapp", path+'\my_project\\templates')

print(list_of_temp)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вас не смущает комбинация \ и \\ в путях? Меня вот да. Замените во всех случаях на \\.

Comment: @V-Mor тоже самое получилось, я про ошибку

Comment: Вот теперь можно думать дальше. Запускаете как? Из IDE или консоли?

Comment: @V-Mor из IDE запускаю

Comment: А закиньте ещё как-нибудь структуру папок свою. Всех, с которыми работаете. Желательно, сделайте `tree` из cmd в папке, которая у Вас path и вывод в вопрос закиньте картинкой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По сути, как говорится [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/modul-os-python/funktsija-replace-modulja-os/), функция `os.replace` **заменяет имя** файла или каталога. То есть, она работает не совсем, как обычное перемещение (типа `move` в cmd). В данном случае вторым аргументом следует передавать не путь к каталогу, **в который** Вы хотите переместить свою папку, а **новый путь** к своей папке, который будет после перемещения (**включая название самой папки**). Если перевести в код:

```python
os.replace(path+"\\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp", path+'\\my_project\\templates\\authapp')
os.replace(path+"\\my_project\\mainapp\\templates\\mainapp", path+'\\my_project\\templates\\mainapp')
```

Вот так, по идее, должно работать.

Comment: Теперь просто не может найти: File "D:/scripts123/Август_Фавн_dz_7/project_2/main.py", line 15, in <module>
    os.replace(path+"\\my_project\\mainapp\\templates\\mainapp", path+'\\my_project\\templates\\mainapp')
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл: 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\mainapp\\templates\\mainapp' -> 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\templates\\mainapp'
Сейчас в свой вопрос добавлю фото катологов

Comment: @Август, у Вас, видимо, нет какого-то из этих каталогов. Либо того, который перемещаете, либо того, В который перемещаете.

Comment: Хотя почему-то с authapp сработало то, как вы написали

Comment: @Август, у Вас точно есть папка \my_project\mainapp\\templates\\mainapp? там она не раскрыта на картинке

Comment: сейчас добавил, но теперь отказано в доступе

Comment: @Август текст ошибки снова покажите

Comment: Вот: File "D:/scripts123/Август_Фавн_dz_7/project_2/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.replace(path+"\\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp", path+'\\my_project\\templates\\authapp')
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\authapp\\templates\\authapp' -> 'D:\\scripts123\\Август_Фавн_dz_7\\project_2\\my_project\\templates\\authapp'

Comment: @Август, ох не хватает тут смайла а'ля палм-фейс. Вы когда первый раз запускали, когда у Вас вторая строка не сработала, первая то сработала. И **переместила** эту папку. Ясное дело её теперь нет. Или Вы восстановили её обратно?

Comment: Мое почтение, получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: @Август, Рад помочь :) Не забывайте впредь убеждаться в существовании того, что перемещаете :)